# TYPO3 - Pass a variable from Fluid to a cObject

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I'm using fluidcontent and I would like to render a plugin in a content-element. Therefore I created the following COA:

```
form = COA
form {
     15 < tt_content.list.20.extname_form
     15.settings.id = |
}
```

This object is getting rendered in the fluid template with the cOject viewhelper.

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="form" data="testId" />
```

The rendering process works fine.

The problem is that I can't access the data variable inside the COA object. In the form template the content of the variable settings.id is `|` and not `testId`.

I tried to render the plugin with the vhs viewhelper request.render, but also there I have the problem passing variables.

```
<v:render.request action="request" controller="Form" extensionName="ExtName" pluginName="Form" vendorName="VendorName" arguments="{_all}" />
```

Answer (score 4):

There is another way using a global registry for variables. TYPO3 contains a so-called "LOAD REGISTER" which means a static storage for variables. The VHS extension contains ViewHelpers to interact with that storage:

https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/master/Variable/Register/GetViewHelper.html

Using the `set` variant you can add your variable, then call `f:cObject` and regardless of how deep inside the rendering stack your next fluid template sits, using the `get` variant retrieves the value.

Very useful if for example you use content elements with other nested content elements, e.g. retrieve or re-define the value at any nesting depth.

NB: also accessible in TypoScript as well as custom PHP executed through TYPO3, by using https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/LoadRegister/Index.html. So overall it may be much, much simpler to handle and definitely more flexible than strict passing of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

just some help (maybe) in your fluid template you can use :

```
<f:debug>{_all}</f:debug>
```

so you can check the lot of information available, otherwise in your controller:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump($yourVariable);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define a String as data use the `.current = 1` option of stdWrap:

```
form = COA
form {
     15 < tt_content.list.20.extname_form
     15.settings.id.current = 1
}
```

But your "extname_form" should use the stdWrap on the settings else you should use "variables":

```
form = COA
form {
     15 < tt_content.list.20.extname_form
     15.variables.id = TEXT
     15.variables.id.current = 1
}
```

---

Example for use of stdWrap for settings:

```
form = COA
form {
     15 < tt_content.list.20.extname_form
     15.settings.id.current = 1
}
```

In your controller action:

```
  /** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Service\TypoScriptService $typoScriptService */
  $typoScriptService = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Service\TypoScriptService::class);
  $typoScriptSettings = $typoScriptService->convertTypoScriptArrayToPlainArray($this->settings);
  $this->settings['id'] = $this->configurationManager->getContentObject()->stdWrap($typoScriptSettings['id'], $typoScriptSettings['id.']);
```

Now your settings.id is parsed by stdWrap and should contain your cObjectViewHelper Data.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried  both versions but I can't pass the variable to the fluid template of the form.

Comment: There could be somethings in your ```extname_form``` Extension that depend on how to access variables. To examples with "variables" only work if the ```tt_content.list.20.extname_form``` is an FLUID_TEMPLATE object. Without knowing the extension you have to parse the settings in your controller and assign them to your view.

Comment: I can't get it to work. Also in the form controller I can't access the variables. The form plugin is also implemented with fluidtemplate. If I use the first version I see the variable in the template. The problem there is that the variable content is not taken.

Comment: I have edited my answer with an example for use of ```stdWrap``` within settings

Comment: I'm sorry, but it does not work. I'm don't get the content of the variable.
I'm calling the typoscript object like that:
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="form" data="{settings.id}" />
Is that correct?

Comment: Than I muss pass. I have no more ideas and unfortunately not enough time to reconstruct your environment to try :(